# "it seems that" vs "it seems as if"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

I was wondering what are the differences among the following:

1. it seems that Young-woo is autistic.
2. it seems as if Young-woo is autistic.
3. it seems as though Young-woo is autistic.
4. it seems like Young-woo is autistic.

I happened to see #3 sentence in the English sub of Korean TV series, Extraordinary Attorney Woo, and I felt the doctor should have said SEEM THAT instead of SEEM AS THOUGH because SEEM AS THOUGH sounds less confident considering he is a professional in health care. I wonder whether all the above expressions have the same meaning.
Is the reason he picked up the words, SEEM AS THOUGH instead of SEEM THAT because he needed yet to look further into her symptoms and health conditions?

DOCTOR: You said Young-woo can't talk even though she's five years old?

Young-woo's FATHER: Yes.

DOCTOR: Not even simple words like mom or dad?

Young-woo's FATHER: No, not at all.

DOCTOR: We'll have to look further into it, but it seems as though Young-woo is autistic.

Merriam Websters' dictionary says SEEM means to appear to be something or to do something, and to my knowledge, SEEM is used to express being less definite, so I feel SEEM THAT, SEEM AS IF, SEEM AS THOUGH, and SEEM LIKE are alike, and I cannot tell their differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, there is no difference in meaning.

To me, the first of the three conveys more likelihood that he actually does know the answer, but it's very subtle.